# mysql statement not executing or is it?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm new to back end work and this i'm just having a play round with it i have a database with some data in it and when i try and do a query on it, it just wont return anything, i tested to see if it was connected also using mysql_ping() and it returned 1.

```
<?php
/*Database*/
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$pw = '';


$conDB = new PDO('mysql:host = $host;dbname = $username', $username,$pw) or die("cant connect");


if($conDB){
echo 'connection made';
}
else{
echo 'error';
}

$clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$statement = $conDB->prepare("
   SELECT * FROM `ip log`
 ");
$statement->execute();


foreach($statement as $test){
 echo $test['Address'];
}

 /*
 $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $res;
*/

?>
```

Comment: what's the name of your table in database?

Comment: the name of it is 'ip log'

Comment: What does `var_dump($test)` show?

Comment: Try enabling PDO exceptions as described in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: You need to put double quotes around the DSN, not single quotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: it shows nothing when i use var_dump just tried then

Comment: You can't use `mysql_ping()` with PDO, they're totally unrelated APIs.